# Asp.Mvc helper method for jQuery DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, html-helper

I am created Asp.Mvc helper method for jQuery DataTable. In this I need to allow developer customise the grid column using mvc @helper method like below.

```
@Html.Grid<ModelClass>()
.GridColumns(a=>{
  a.column.Bound(a=>a.ID)
    .ServerSideTemplate(t => DisplayTemplae(d));
})

@helper DisplayTemplae(ModelClass data)
{
   <b>data.Name</b>
}
```

Currently I was I implemented **ServerSideTemplate** function like below

```
 public static IDTOptionsSer<T> ServerSideTemplate<T>(this IDTOptionsSer<T> table, Func<T, IHtmlString> constraint)
   {
        Func<T, string> valueContraint = a => constraint(a).ToHtmlString();
        table.RowTemplate(valueContraint); 
        return table;
   }
```

The method `table.RowTemplate(valueContraint)` save the valueContraint in dtTableColumn  attribute class `property ColunServerSideTemplate`.

Then I process the data table data  from server side like bellow

```
foreach(item in _source.DtTableData){

   _source.column(a=>{
         a.column.ColunServerSideTemplate(item);
    });   
}
```

It will work for some 1000 of records. But if my records is more then frequently I got memory out of bound exception.

How can I handle this?